# Filipino married to British wants to visit England

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipina married to my British husband, and we both live in the Philippines. We are planning to visit his family in England for few weeks to meet them in person. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

I think since you have no intention of living in the UK and will (and show proof too) return to the Philipines you would need a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa)

Of course, you will have to fulfill the [eligibility criteria](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility) and apply with all of the relevant supporting [documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf).

You should be able to apply online at the visas/immigration services website: https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa

Comment: In this case, since the asker is married to a British citizen, UKVI may be particularly concerned that he is bring back his spouse to settle in the UK. They should include plenty of evidence of the ties that their spouse has to the Philippines (work, property ownership etc.), in addition to their own ties to the Philippines, to help their chances of success.

Comment: Yep, that would be the major, if not only, deciding factor in the issuance of the visa.